# XCode script to take screenshots of xib windows

Tags: xcode, user-interface, applescript

As part of the QA process i want to start an xcode project and step through  all xib files taking screenshots of the windows (with all the localized variants) and save them for fast auditing and as a hint i can send to translators and other involved people.

Is there any way to do this with an applescript script?

P.S: I work on an old fashioned macOS app.

Comment: What?  Why does this get downvoted?

Comment: This may be possible with Xcode 8 when it is released in the fall.  The engineers at WWDC 2016 said that there will be much more robust support for AppleScript in the next version.

Comment: I have the XCode 8 beta. What they said at WWDC was that they had re-written the AS support. I'm not finding anything in it relating to the interface builder screens. You're probably better off using a screen capture program like "Grab"

Comment: @RonReuter: I installed XCode8 today  and found the same. The Apple Script dictionary is very very small and only for building and changing build settings. The release notes say that even file/text manipulations are not stable. So it's all about the improved CI.  Not bad, but not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Solved? This is a great question.